Determining contrasts for a moderated regression
I have a study design with 4 treatment conditions (A, B, C, and a control group) and a continuous moderator (Mod). I am examining the effect of the treatment as well as its interaction with Mod on a dependent variable (Y).
My hypotheses are:
H1: Y will be higher in all treatment conditions (A, B, and C) compared to the control condition.
H2: Y will be higher in condition A compared to B and C, particularly when Mod is higher.
I am planning to use orthogonal contrasts to code the treatment variable. My proposed contrasts are:
C1: A = -1, B = -1, C = -1, Control = 3 (testing the difference between the treatments and the control)
C2: A = 2, B = -1, C = -1, Control = 0 (testing A vs. B and C combined)
C3: A = 0, B = -1, C = 1, Control = 0 (testing B vs. C)
I intend to run a multiple regression that includes these contrasts and their interactions with Mod. I expect that C1 and C2*Mod will be significant to support my two hypotheses.
Would this approach be correct?
Additionally, I’m considering an alternative hypothesis:
H1 : Y will be highest in condition A, followed by B and C (which are expected to be equal), and lowest in the control condition.
H2 : This pattern should be especially true when Mod is higher.
In this case, I don't know how to code the contrasts to reflect the expected pattern. Does anyone have suggestions on how to set up contrast coding/analysis for this scenario?

I find it very hard to set up contrasts so that the reported regression coefficients directly evaluate all of the hypotheses in question. A safer way (for me, at least) to accomplish your goals would be to run the regression model first, without any regard to specific hypotheses when coding your predictors. Default coding should work OK.
Then use post-modeling analysis, drawing on the regression coefficient estimates and their covariances, to examine each of your hypotheses. The results will be the same as if you coded the predictors with those hypotheses in mind.
The R emmeans package provides a useful collection of tools to that end, with extensive documentation. It's quite good for illustrating what's going on when there's a continuous predictor involved in an interaction (moderation).
